Построение графика логистической регрессии для векторизованных данных
Всем привет. Решал задачу по распознаванию спама, используя разные методы классификации, такие как Naive Bayes, Log regression, тем самым тестируя что работает лучше.
Проблема: Никак не получается отрисовать график для логистической регрессии.
Полный код. Датасет взят из Kaggle.
Ход работы:

Прочитал файл и сделал data cleaning.
Так как данные в виде текста, проделал векторизацию текста и LabelEncoding.
Применил функцию лог регрессии.
Отрисовал график таким образом:

y_pred = y_pred.squeeze()
y_prob = model.predict_proba(X_test_vectorized)

# Plot scatter plot
sns.scatterplot(x= range(len(y_pred)), y=y_pred, hue= Y_test)
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(x = range(len(y_pred)), y = y_prob[:,1], hue = Y_test)
plt.xlabel('Text Feature')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.legend()
plt.show()




Что значит "не получается"? Покажите тот график, который у вас нарисовался этим кодом.

@CrazyElf не нарисовалось ничего. Я вставил ссылку на ноутбук. Интерпретатор жалуется на строку x_test_view = X_test_vectorized['text'].values.squeeze() и выдает ошибку IndexError: Index dimension must be 1 or 2.

Ага, я посмотрел код. А что вы хотите нарисовать, собственно? Попробуйте для начала такой x взять для отрисовки: x=range(len(y_pred)). Это будет просто порядковый номер образца данных.

@CrazyElf сделал - та же ошибка. Пытался сделать как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446699/matplotlib-plot-curve-logistic-regression. Или тут https://www.kaggle.com/code/aakritsinghal/logistic-regression-visualisation

Ну в смысле либо вообще строку с x_test_view =  уберите, либо сделайте x_test_view = range(len(y_pred)), если вам так понятнее.

А что касается указанных примеров, то у вас же векторное представление данных, как вы его по оси x собираетесь изображать? Тут самое простое, как я написал выше, просто по порядку образцы пересчитать и порядковый номер на оси x написать. Выровнять векторные данные в цепочку, как вы это делаете - не поможет.

@Crazyelf да, на сей раз сделал как надо, но получился график который ваще не логрег, не понимаю. Фотку выложил в самом вопросе.

А вы нарисуйте отдельно графики, а не два в одном. Для этого перед вторым графиком сделайте plt.figure(). На первом графике будут предсказания 0 и 1, это и будет логистическая регрессия. На втором графике будут предсказания вероятностей, до применения порога отсечения. На этом графике можно прозрачность поставить для наглядности, например alpha=0.3, ну это по вкусу. Но если вы что-то типа линии хотите увидеть y = a*x + b, то тут такого не будет, конечно, у вас же не одна переменная в данных, а много-много столбцов. Векторное представление может тысячи столбцов иметь.

Хотите нарисовать что-то красивое из ваших данных - попробуйте посмотреть в сторону t-SNE и прочего такого https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html

Вообще, если у вас такая простая модель как логистическая регрессия, то можете брать фичи по одной и для каждой отдельно рисовать график: значение фичи - целевая переменная/предсказание. Вот там вполне себе возможно будет прямо линия на втором графике. Но самих этих графиков у вас будет ну очень много же - по длине векторного представления. X_test_vectorized[:, i]

Сложно сказать. Если бы вы разобрались как чего и сами потом дали на свой вопрос развёрнутый ответ - это было бы полезно. Но это не простая работа )

@Crazyelf Ответил на свой вопрос. Оцените пожалуйста, может что исправить?

Ну, пойдёт, хотя я бы описание шагов и код разделил. Код нормально форматируется и воспринимается только когда он сам по себе. И в целом всё-равно не очень понятно, как интерпретировать получившееся )

Построить график логистической регрессии в привычном виде в данном случае не получится, т.к в этом коде проводится векторизация текста, которая приводит к тому, что количество признаков (фич) резко возрастает. В результате, вместо нескольких переменных у нас получается большое количество признаков
В данном случае разумно использовать метод уменьшения размерности t-SNE,которая помогает визуализировать данные, уменьшив их до двух или трех измерений, что делает результаты работы алгоритма более наглядными.

Сначало выбираем 1000 точек из данных. Для целей визуализации достаточно меньшего подмножества данных. Даже 1000 точек часто достаточно, чтобы получить представление о структуре данных и различиях между классами.
Выбираем модель, в данном случае логрег
Объявляем и фитим t-SNE
Создаем датафрейм для результатов
Отрисовка графика

data_1000 = X_train_scaled[0:1000, :]  
labels_1000 = labels[0:1000]
model = LogisticRegression(random_state = 42)
model.fit(data_1000, labels_1000)
transformed_data = model.predict_proba(data_1000)
tsne_model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, init='random')  
tsne_data = tsne_model.fit_transform(transformed_data)
tsne_data = np.vstack((tsne_data.T, labels_1000)).T  
tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tsne_data, columns=("Dim_1", "Dim_2", "label"))  
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))   
sns.scatterplot(data=tsne_df, x='Dim_1', y='Dim_2', hue='label', palette="bright")    
plt.xlabel("Component 1")    
plt.ylabel("Component 2")    
plt.title("Scatter plot of t-SNE results after applying Logistic Regression")     
plt.legend()   
plt.show()

Итог: 
